# What encoding is this BK-0010-01 FOCAL file in?

Tags: pdp-11, electronika-bk, focal

I want to keep copies of the programs I write in BK FOCAL on my modern laptop, and in the end to be able to transfer text file programs to the BK.

My current system for transferring files between the two computers is via a 1 GB flash memory, which I read/write with the BKHDDTool, and then inspect and extract files with the BKDE tool (both from [here](https://gid.pdp-11.ru/downloads.html).

The thing is that I can indeed extract the files I have written on the BK, but when I do so they have a particular formatting which makes them hard to read, and while I could probably strip them down with vim (and so later with sed), I would have a much harder time creating my own files without understanding what is going on.

I do know that when I use FOCAL, it somehow engages with the [ANDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANDOS) disk operating system, as it is ANDOS that prompts me whether I want to overwrite files.

I also wonder if this has anything to do with Russian ASCII extensions such as some KOI-7 or KOI-8 variant.

To make my question easier to answer to those who know, here is a simple FOCAL program

```
01.10 T "HELLO WORLD"
```

as it appears when I open it in GNU Emacs:

```
^T^@^@^@C:\346\357\353\341\354-\342\3530010\216^@\376\373\^Y^AT\200"HELLO\200WORLD"\216
```

Note that my code can be seen in there:

> ^T^@^@^@C:\346\357\353\341\354-\342\353**0010**\216^@\376\373^Y^A**T**\200"**HELLO**\200**WORLD"**\216

and that when I try to copy-paste from Emacs into this browser for example I get some interpretation of the characters:

> \0\0\0C:  �����-��0010�\0��T�"HELLO�WORLD"�

I provide each of these versions in case they shed any additional light on the situation.

I also tried hexl-mode in emacs:

```
00000000: 1400 0000 433a 2020 e6ef ebe1 ec2d e2eb  ....C:  .....-..
00000010: 3030 3130 8e00 fefb 1901 5480 2248 454c 0010......T."HEL
00000020: 4c4f 8057 4f52 4c44 228e LO.WORLD".
```

When I run

```
file -bi
```

on the file in Linux Mint, I get

```
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

I have asked on a Telegram chat dedicated to the BK series, and got the answer that it was the encoding of BK Focal, so I wonder if this might be similar to the encoding of PDP-11 Focal as the BK series are PDP 11/03 clones?

If I can figure out the pattern of these files (for example \200 seems to be a space), how can I then build similar files to put them back onto the BK?

Comment: Generally, BK used KOI-8.